# How can I resolve Windows vs Linux properties file paths?

Tags: java, linux, jenkins

I have a java project on a Windows box which builds successfully and all tests pass locally.  This project is then checked in and built with Jenkins on a Linux box.

The problem I am having is related to path issues in my properties file which is used for running tests.  I point to a resources dir for part of a file path like this:  "./src/test/resources".

I am trying to access two files which reside in the same directory.  File1 is accessed successfully.  Then File2 access is attempted, but it returns a file not found exception.

I've tried using an absolute path like this: "/code/myproject/main/src/test/resources/..."  This again works on my local box, but not on Jenkins because Jenkins only knows about" "/myproject/main/src/test/resources/..."

How can this be resolved?

Comment: try using relative path from work space.. it may solve your problems in Ex:`$Workspace/$projectname/<resources path>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I learned Linux is case sensitive.  The file name extension is upper case, but I was pointing to a lower case one.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Windows... Windows 7 (don't know since when this was implemented) understand linux-style `/` separator just fine, as long as the whole path is relative.

Comment: I am using Windows 8.